# Cannot index certain values of vector created with seq() and rep()

Tags: r, indexing, sum, seq, rep

I have created a vector x that contains a sequence from 0 to 1, where each value is replicated 100 times. When I display the vector, it looks just fine. However, indexing does not work for all of x's unique values.

```
x.seq <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)
x <- rep(x.seq, each = 100)

x
x == 0.7
x == 0.70
```

x shows the expected result, however `x == 0.70` shows only `FALSE`'s. I'm very confused, as this is not the case for every value. E.g. trying `x == 0.99`, I get the expected results with 100 `TRUE`'s.

Strikingly, when I tried a workaround via `unique()`, indexing works again:

```
unique(x)[71]     # as a workaround for x = 0.7
x == unique(x)[71]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help("==")`

> For numerical and complex values, remember `==` and `!=` **do not allow for the finite representation of fractions, nor for rounding error**. Using all.equal with identical is almost always preferable. See the examples. (This also applies to the other comparison operators.)

We're running into a numerical problem.

```
x.seq[71] - 0.7
# [1] 1.110223e-16
```

From looking at the source of `seq.default`, the 71st value of `seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.01)` is `0 + 70 * 0.01`, and `70 * 0.01 == 0.7` is indeed `FALSE` on my machine.